# Proving that $P(B|C \cap A^{c}) = P(B|C)$

Tags: probability, solution-verification, conditional-probability, independence

I was solving the following question:

> Most mornings, Victor checks the weather report before deciding whether to carry an umbrella.
> If the forecast is “rain,” the probability of actually having rain that day is 80%.
> On the other hand, if the forecast is “no rain,” the probability of it actually raining is equal to 10%.
>
> During fall and winter, the forecast is “rain” 70% of the time and during summer and spring, it is 20%.
>
> The probability of Victor missing the morning forecast is equal to 0.2
> on any day in the year. If he misses the forecast, Victor will flip a
> fair coin to decide whether to carry an umbrella.
>
> On any day of a given season, he sees the forecast, if it says “rain” he will always
> carry an umbrella, and if it says “no rain,” he will not carry an
> umbrella. Are the events “Victor is carrying an umbrella,” and “The
> forecast is no rain” independent? Does your answer depend on the
> season?

And my attempt to solve it is as following:

> Let A be the event of the forecast is "rain".
>
> Let B be the event of Victor carrying an umbrella.
>
> Let C be the event of Victor misses the forecast.

From the statement we have that:
$$P(A) = 0.2 \space or \space 0.7 $$
$$P(B|A) = 0.8 $$
$$P(B|A^{c}) = 0.1 $$
$$p(C) = 0.2$$

So we must prove that B and A are independent events.

Since $A^{c}$ has non-zero probability we can prove independence by proving that:

$$P(B|A^{c}) = P(B)$$

From Total Probability Theorem, we can write:
$$P(B) = P(C)P(B|C) + P(C^{c})P(B|C^{c})$$
Since $P(B|C^{c}) = P(A)$ (Because if he doesn't miss the forecast then he will carry an umbrella if the forecast is "rain"), then:
$$\implies P(B) = (0.2)(0.5)+ (0.8)P(A)$$
$$\implies P(B) = 0.1 + (0.8)P(A)$$

Now Also from the Total Probability Theorem, we can write:
$$P(B|A^{c}) = P(C)P(B|C \cap A^{c}) + P(C^{c})P(B|C^{c} \cap A^{c})$$

It's obvious that $P(B|C \cap A^{c}) = P(B|C)$, and from that It's easy to complete solving the problem.

My question is how we can prove that $P(B|C \cap A^{c}) = P(B|C)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't find a formal proof of this, I'll write the best result that I come up with, I think it's the solution and please correct me if I'm wrong.

Proving that: $P(B| C \cap A^{c}) = P(B | C)$ is tell us that the two events A and B are conditionally independent (that condition is C here).

Since B is determined by a random process `If he misses the forecast, Victor will flip a fair coin to decide whether to carry an umbrella` then we can say that B is independent from A since flipping a fair coin is not related by any way to A and have a fixed probability which equal to 0.5 .